# Angular2 detect presence of ng-content target

Tags: javascript, angular

I have not seen how to do more complex stuff using content projection in Angular2. And the basic example i could imagine is some Modal that could have (or not have) header.

You will have smth like:

Modal template

```
<div class="my-modal">
  <div class="my-modal__header">
   <ng-content select="my-modal-header"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="my-modal__content">
    <ng-content select="my-modal-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<my-modal>
  <my-modal-header>HEADER</my-modal-header>
  <my-modal-content>Content</my-modal-content>
</my-modal>
```

And the problem is:

1) i would like to hide header wrappers if header was not provided (e.g. hide "my-modal__header")

2) i would like to show some default header if header content is not provide (e.g. show "This is header" if header not provided

or smth similar.

How to detect presence of ng-content with exact target?

I've done some plunkr to play around with example: https://plnkr.co/edit/QfBJjD3g82ksTjU5zVqw?p=preview

Comment: Why the question was marked as duplicated?

1) It has some similarities, but it does not work for my exact example - most of times, i guess, you have some wrappers above the projected element, that you want to hide. In that case #ref will not work, because its not there. Moreover, if you are trying to declare some value after view init - you will get an error - "Expression has changed after it was checked."

2) Checking childNodes to detect presence of projected element - sounds a bit wrong, if its a bit.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I face the exact same problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Stnaire nope, using variable still :( e.g. "hasFooter"